# Sleep operation in C++, platform : windows

Tags: c++, windows, sleep

I want to perform the above mentioned operation in Milliseconds as the unit. Which library and function call should I prefer ?

Ty.

Comment: The [Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686298%28VS.85%29.aspx) function?

Comment: Are you quite sure sleep is the best solution? It usually isn't.

Comment: If you need to sleep for a few milliseconds note that  sleep() may have a resolution of 10ms or more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the [Sleep](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function from Win32 API.

Comment: LOL. Same first google link but you beat me to it by 45 secs.

Answer (score 6):

Or if you are using Visual Studio 2010 (or another c++0x aware compiler) use

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

std::this_thread::sleep();

// or
std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(10));
```

With older compilers you can have the same convenience using the relevant [Boost Libraries](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.this_thread)

**Needless to say** the major benefit here is **portability** and the ease of converting the delay parameter to 'human' units.

Comment: @OldPeculier Which just means that this is now the generally applicable answer, years down the road :)

Answer (score 2):

the windows task scheduler has a granularity far above 1ms (generally, 20ms). you can test this by using the performance counter to measure the time really spent in the `Sleep()` function. (using `QueryPerformanceFrequency()` and `QueryPerformanceCounter()` allows you to measure time down to the nanosecond). note that `Sleep(0)` makes the thread sleep for the shortest period of time possible.

however, you can change this behavior by using [`timeBeginPeriod()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd757624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and passing a 1ms period. now `Sleep(0)` should return much faster.

note that this function call was made for playing multimedia streams with a better accuracy. i have never had any problem using this, but the need for such a fast period is quite rare. depending on what you are trying to achieve, there may be better ways to get the accuracy you want, without resorting to this "hack".

Answer (score 0):

Er, the sleep() function from win32 api?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx